# Why are there so many users running together on KDE Neon?

Tags: kde-neon

When I open KSysGuard just after logging in, I see more than 200 active processes by default and most of them are running using `root` account and there're a few others alongside root namely `rtkit`, `avahi`, `daemon`, `lp`, `messagebus`, `syslog`, etc.! I neither have activated `root` account nor have created any of those users by my own on my PC!

As far as I remember, I hadn't seen any of those users when I used Ubuntu 18.04, CentOS 7, Fedora 30, OpeSUSE Leap 15.1. All processes were always owned by and were running under my account in those OSs.

How do they get into my system every time I log in to KDE Neon and what do they do actually? Is KDE Neon OS a client application running on my PC for others usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to worry about, these are all system users created from your system or maybe some installed software. I think you just didn't look for the users of running processes when using the other OS'.

I too have all mentioned users running processes on my Ubuntu 16.04. Only one difference: `message+` instead of `messagebus`, the rest is the exact same.
I have even some more: `colord`, `nobody`, `systemd+`, `nx`.

Have a look at `/etc/passwd`, where all user accounts are listed.
The first field is the username, the last field shows their shell. This is usually `/sbin/nologin` or similar for system users.

- `lp` is a printer service.
- `avahi` implements `zeroconf` for managing network connections.
- `syslog` is obviously the `syslog` service
- `rtkit` is a `dbus` process/thread scheduler service.
- ...

As these services run system wide, they cannot run from your account. And for security and probably also other implications, they should not run from the `root` account. So they implement own *system* users.

---

I use `ps aux | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c` to show all users currently running processes and how many for each. `root` runs 195 processes rigth now.

For the  Gnome System Monitor to show all processes instead of only your own ones, change the preferences:

[image]

Comment: right now I've buntu 18.04, CentOS 7 and OpenSUSE 15.1 on virtual box, all processes there are associated with my user account, nothing else there. If I log in as root in OpenSUSE or CentOS then root becomes the owner of those processes and what I also have known that I actually can't log in as root in Ubuntu!

Comment: Do you have any process using root account? I haven't had a count BUT more than 150 processes are using root account for sure in my KDE Neon right now!

Comment: `ps aux | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c` is the command I use to see the users running processes and how many ... `root` currently runs 195 processes.

Comment: hmm, so the GNOME system monitor hides the rest for some reason!

Comment: The reason is how you or your system configured the system monitor. And it seems, Neon has the default setting set to "All Processes". In Ubuntu it's set to "My Processes" only.